# Delegates vs. Events

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, delegates

When a class can't (or should not) do something, then events or delegates could be a solution.

say

```
class President
  Event AskedQuestion(QuestionEventArgs)
  Delegate GetAnswerToQuestion

class Scientist
  AnswerToQuestion()

// delegate approach
myPresident.GetAnswerToQuestion = AddressOf myScientist.AnswerToQuestion
// called once myPresident need it

// event approach
myScientist.AnswerToQuestion(questionEventArgs) Handles President.AskedQuestion
{ 
   // executed once president asked a question
}
```

Here in the delegate approach Scientist method is used directly by the President class, in the event one President raises a question, and the Scientist react to it with an answer.

In the .NET Framework code I didn't observe, however the direct use of delegates. Is it wrong to use it directly, and if, why?

Answer (score 9):

> Is it wrong to use it directly, and if, why?

No, it's not wrong.

Here's how I think about it.  Delegate fields are to events as string fields are to properties. That is, you might have:

```
class Car
{
    private string modelName;
    public string ModelName { get { return this.modelName; } }
    ...
```

The model name is *logically* a property of a car. When someone asks you what kind of car you drive and you say "a Ford Focus", you are describing a property of the car. You do not think of "Ford Focus" as being a "field" or a "string", you think of it as being the name of a kind of car. In the computer program, the string field is just the implementation detail of how the name is stored. The property could be a string, or it could be an enum, or whatever; the point is that logically, cars have model names, not string fields.

Events and delegates are the same way. A car can have an "explode" event (perhaps you are writing a video game!) and the explode event is implemented by a field of delegate type. Exploding is something the car logically does; the delegate field is the mechanism by which the event is implemented.

So is it "wrong" to use delegates directly? No, of course not. No more than it is "wrong" to use strings directly. Sometimes you need to manipulate strings that are not properties, and sometimes you need to manipulate delegates that are not events.

The trick is to write code that clearly separates the *mechanical* processes from the *business* processes. If you find that you're mixing a lot of string logic with your property logic, or mixing a lot of delegate manipulation with your events, then you might consider trying to separate the mechanism code from the business code a bit more, so that it is easier to see which is which.

Comment: apropos, Microsoft does not recommend http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87%28v=vs.80%29.aspx using public fields directly, but wrapping them into properties...

Comment: @serhio: That's an even better way of making my point. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: I don't think so. If you see delegates as fields and Events as properties, the use of public delegates should be restricted, like the use of public fields.

Comment: @serhio: delegates are *types*, like strings. It's perfectly acceptable to manipulate instances of delegates, just as it is perfectly acceptable to implement instances of strings. That it is a bad idea to expose a public field has nothing to do with the *type* of the field; that's my point.

Comment: @Eric: besides the *types* delegates are *pointers* to functions. Exposing them as public could imply some security risks like described Moussa.

Comment: @serhio: Oh, sure, there are all kinds of security issues with delegates; but there are security issues with events as well. If you let untrusted code add events handlers to your buttons, and then someone clicks the button and something bad happens. The ability to pass around behaviour the same way you pass around data is in general a dangerous thing to do, so be careful if you have partial-trust scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of use of delegates in the framework. LINQ is a clear example of this:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(input => input.MatchesSomeCriteria);
```

`Where` takes a delegate with a specific signature which is invoked in order to determine whether to include an item in the result or not. The most common use is the lamba approach as shown above, but you can just as well pass a method:

```
string[] nums = new[]{ "1", "2", "3"};
int sum = nums.Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

`int.Parse` matches the required delegate signature that `Select` expects in this case (`Func<string,int>`), so it will be invoked for each of the strings in `nums`.

Typically when delegates are used directly, they are taken as input to method calls that will consume them. There are some places where they are part of the consumers state though ([`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) for instance has a few properties that are of delegate types), but they are not that many.

Comment: say, lambda expressions and LINQ is in a way "implicit" use of delegates. Explicit use of it I think was not very popular, especially in the pre-LINQ era, when it were used in a few things like comparators...

Comment: @sergio - maybe that could be said about anonymous delegates but the use of the delegate type has always been a fundamental part of the framework.

Comment: @David: do YOU use delegates in your custom classes?

Comment: Delegates are used all the time with events.
For Example: public event EventHandler<GridViewRowClickedEventArgs> RowClicked;

Comment: Or multithreaded callbacks. There's often a need to pass a reference to a method without actually invoking it.

Comment: @Magnus: I think @serhio means that the question is about the *direct* use of delegates, as opposed to using them together with events.

Comment: @Magnus: Delegates are not used all the time with events, rather events always use delegates... anyway, the question is rather should we use public delegates in our custom classes or not.

Answer (score 1):

working with delegates in the raw can entail some
boilerplate code (defining the delegate, declaring necessary member variables, and creating custom
registration/unregistration methods to preserve encapsulation, etc.).

Typing time aside, another issue with using delegates in the raw as your application’s callback
mechanism is the fact that if you do not define a class’s delegate member variables as private, the
caller will have direct access to the delegate objects. If this were the case, the caller would be able to
reassign the variable to a new delegate object (effectively deleting the current list of functions to
call) and worse yet, the caller would be able to directly invoke the delegate’s invocation list.

Answer (score 1):

**events**

events are actually one of the things that I really like about .net becuase it lets you declare a much cleaner interface.  You can have a president class that announces that it needs an answer without binding it to the implementation of the answering agent like

```
interface IPresident
{
     event Action<QuestionArgs, IPresident> HasQuestion;
     void RecieveAnswer(QuestionArgs,Answer);
}
```

and then in your scientist class

```
partial class Scientist
{
     public Scientist(IPresident president)
     {
          president.HasQuestion += TryToAnswerQuestion;

     }

     private void TryToAnswerQuestion(QuestionArgs question, IPresident asker)
     {
         if(CanAnswerQuestion(question))
         {
             asker.RecieveAnswer(question,GetAnswer(question));
         }
     }
}
```

If a new class wants to answer the presidents questions all they need to do is listen for the event signaling that there is a question that needs to be answered and then answer it if they are able to.  If the scientist wants to answer questions from someone else we just need to implement a method that attaches to their Event.

**direct delegate invocation**

The problem with the delegate approach that you outlined above is that it breaks encapsulation.  It tightly couples the scientist and president implementations and makes the code brittle.  What happens when you have some other person that answers questions? In your example you are going to need to modify your Scientist implementation in order to add new functionality this is referred to as "brittle" code and is a bad thing.  This technique does have some role in composition but it will only rarely, if ever, be the best choice.

the linq case is different, because you aren't exposing a delegate as a member of a class/interface.  Instead you are using it as a functor declared by the caller to let you know what information the caller is interested in.  Since you are making a "round-trip" encapsulation stays intact.
This lets you define very clean and powerful APIs.

We could take the Scientist example and extend it using this technique to allow someone to find out what questions we can answer like this

```
 partial class Scientist
 {
     public IEnumerable<QuestionArgs> FindQuestions(Predicate<QuestionArgs> interest, IPresident asker)
     {
         return this.Questions.Where( x => interest(x) == true && x.IsAuthorizedToAsk(asker))
     }
 }

 // ...

partial class President
{
    FirePhysicists()
    {
        foreach(var scientist in scientists)
        {
             if(scientist.FindQuestions(x => x.Catagory == QuestionCatagory.Physics, this).Count != 0)
             {
                 scientist.Fire();
             }
         }
      }
 }
```

Note how the `FindQuestions` method let us not have to implement a bunch of other code to interrogate the scientist that we would have needed without the ability pass delegates around. While this isn't the only case where you are going to find delegates invoked directly it is one of the most common ones